# Tikz bucketing diagram (grouped bar chart diagram)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, bar-chart

I'm looking to re-create the following diagram. I figured the easiest way is to create a simple horitzontal bar chart without axes and link them to the respective grouped bar charts? But I don't know how to connect the various sections.

Could somebody provide me?

[image]

Comment: If you provide minimal code for, say, two or three of the bar charts, I bet someone will show you how to connect them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As frougon says, you leave all the work to the one who answers it. You could have come up at least with the data of the bars. You can just use forest.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\newcounter{bary}
\newcommand{\HorBars}[2][]{\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{horizontal bars/.cd,#1}
\setcounter{bary}{0}
\def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/horizontal bars/##1}}%
\edef\tmpbars{#2}%
\edef\tmpnone{none}%
\edef\tmpfilter{\pv{filter}}%
\ifx\tmpnone\tmpfilter
\foreach \X/\Y in \tmpbars
{\stepcounter{bary}
\draw[line width=\pv{bar width},\Y] 
    (0,{(\pv{bar width}+\pv{bar distance})*\value{bary}}) 
    -- ++(\X*\pv{x unit},0);}
\else
\foreach \X/\Y [count=\Z ] in \tmpbars
{\edef\myfilter{\Y}
\ifx\myfilter\tmpfilter
\stepcounter{bary}
\draw[line width=\pv{bar width},\Y] 
    (0,{(\pv{bar width}+\pv{bar distance})*\value{bary}}) 
    -- ++(\X*\pv{x unit},0);
\fi}
\fi 
\end{tikzpicture}}
\tikzset{horizontal bars/.cd,x unit/.initial=2em,bar width/.initial=1em,bar
distance/.initial=0.1em,filter/.initial=none}
\newsavebox\sbars
\newsavebox\sbarsA
\newsavebox\sbarsB
\newsavebox\sbarsC
\newsavebox\sbarsD
\begin{document}
\edef\mybars{2/blue,5/orange,6.5/green,5.5/orange,6/green,2.5/blue,4/red,4/red,%
7/green,4.5/orange,3/blue,3.5/red}%
\savebox\sbars{\HorBars{\mybars}}%
\savebox\sbarsA{\HorBars[filter=blue]{\mybars}}%
\savebox\sbarsB{\HorBars[filter=red]{\mybars}}%
\savebox\sbarsC{\HorBars[filter=orange]{\mybars}}%
\savebox\sbarsD{\HorBars[filter=green]{\mybars}}%

\begin{forest}
forked edges,grow'=east,
for tree={where level=1{anchor=west}{},calign=fixed edge angles,l
sep+=3em,fork sep=2em,s=-2em}
[\usebox\sbars
 [\usebox\sbarsA]
 [\usebox\sbarsB]
 [\usebox\sbarsC]
 [\usebox\sbarsD]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The layout is entirely controlled by `forest`. One can change `l`, `l sep`, `s`, `s sep`, `fork sep` and play with `calign`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\newcounter{bary}
\newcommand{\HorBars}[2][]{\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{horizontal bars/.cd,#1}
\setcounter{bary}{0}
\def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/horizontal bars/##1}}%
\edef\tmpbars{#2}%
\edef\tmpnone{none}%
\edef\tmpfilter{\pv{filter}}%
\ifx\tmpnone\tmpfilter
\foreach \X/\Y in \tmpbars
{\stepcounter{bary}
\draw[line width=\pv{bar width},\Y] 
    (0,{(\pv{bar width}+\pv{bar distance})*\value{bary}}) 
    -- ++(\X*\pv{x unit},0);}
\else
\foreach \X/\Y [count=\Z ] in \tmpbars
{\edef\myfilter{\Y}
\ifx\myfilter\tmpfilter
\stepcounter{bary}
\draw[line width=\pv{bar width},\Y] 
    (0,{(\pv{bar width}+\pv{bar distance})*\value{bary}}) 
    -- ++(\X*\pv{x unit},0);
\fi}
\fi 
\end{tikzpicture}}
\tikzset{horizontal bars/.cd,x unit/.initial=2em,bar width/.initial=1em,bar
distance/.initial=0.1em,filter/.initial=none}
\newsavebox\sbars
\newsavebox\sbarsA
\newsavebox\sbarsB
\newsavebox\sbarsC
\newsavebox\sbarsD
\begin{document}
\edef\mybars{2/blue,5/orange,6.5/green,5.5/orange,6/green,2.5/blue,4/red,4/red,%
7/green,4.5/orange,3/blue,3.5/red}%
\savebox\sbars{\HorBars{\mybars}}%
\savebox\sbarsA{\HorBars[filter=blue]{\mybars}}%
\savebox\sbarsB{\HorBars[filter=red]{\mybars}}%
\savebox\sbarsC{\HorBars[filter=orange]{\mybars}}%
\savebox\sbarsD{\HorBars[filter=green]{\mybars}}%

\begin{forest}
forked edges,grow'=east,
for tree={where level=1{anchor=west}{},
l sep+=3em,fork sep=2em,s sep=0.5em}
[\usebox\sbars,yshift=-6em
 [\usebox\sbarsA]
 [\usebox\sbarsB]
 [\usebox\sbarsC]
 [\usebox\sbarsD]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would really appreciate if not the usual story repeats itself. Someone comes, chances a little detail of this code, and gets all the credit.

Comment: My apologies, I should've provided the bar charts yes. How would I reduce the vertical spacing between the grouped charts on the right?

Comment: @Rashmi You can adjust the `forest` keys. I added an example.